# Listen for directive to have completed loading in DOM - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events, onload-event

I would like to provide a loading indication as long as the directive has not finished loading all it's child elements on the page.

This portion of my app has tabs which when clicked will load the tab content. The problem I have is that some tabs content takes a long time to render.

I assumed it was my HTTP request which was causing a delay in the rendering and resorted to using custom promises, but after implementing that I found it was actually the DOM rendering of the directive that was taking so long.

What would be the correct event to listen to in the directive if I want to display a loading indicator before all the content is rendered within this directive? As far as I know, `$viewContentLoaded` is only used for the `ngView` directive, but this directive is a sub-directive of ngView so it does not apply (i think).

The code is pretty basic:

Controller:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Service', function($scope, Service) {
    
    $scope.get_data = function(user) {
        Service.getsomething(user).then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
    
}])
.directive('tab', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html'
        };
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3" role="tablist">
        <li toggle-tabs class="active">
             <a href="#apanel">Panel</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content col-lg-12">

        <tab></tab> //within here there are many forms

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.module('app').directive('tab', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        $timeout(function () {
          $rootScope.$emit('directive-dom-is-most-likely-there');
        });
      }
  };
});
```

You can't be sure that DOM is there when `link` runs,  it depends on the implementation of nested directives (e.g. `ng-repeat` is known to be a late bloomer). Either you can't be sure that none of them has async stuff that needs some time to be completed, but `$timeout` with zero delay is ok for cosmetic things.

It depends on the context, it is not necessary to pollute `$rootScope` when you can talk to parent directive with `require`.

Keep in mind that it is more straightforward to make the directive self-contained with its own loading indicator instead of the global one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, by using this would I show my loading indicator within my `Service.get_data` call and broadcast an event, and then use `$emit` to indicate that this event is complete? I would like to keep the directive self-contained if possible

Comment: It is not clear how controller and Service are related to tab directive in your example. Are you doing something like `ng-click="get_data(...)` in tab directive?

Comment: What is 'DOM rendering' then? It happens during directive compilation, or the changes in scope apply slowly?  Anyway, it is better to move `get_data` to the directive (or move it to UserService if you use it elsewhere) and let it handle its own state.